# Unable to execute a JavaFX application bundled without JRE

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, gradle, javafx-8

I'm having some troubles trying to deploy a JavaFX application. In order to simplify my problem I've tried to do the same with a "Hello word" application and the problem is the same.

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle.

My `build.gradle` file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: "http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/8.1.1/javafx.plugin"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    mainClass 'Main'
}
```

That `build.gradle` file works. The problem is that it embeds the JRE into the bundle so the file size is about 175 MB. That's too much for a simple "Hello World" app, don't you think?

So, I want to bundle this simple app without the JRE (yes, I know that I should distribute my app with the JRE bundled so it doesn't relay on uses system but I'm going to distribute both versions: with and without JRE bundled). In order to do this I add a single line to the `build.gradle` file (as explained in [this link](http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2013/05/18/javafx-gradle-plugin-0-dot-3-0-released/):

```
...
javafx {
    mainClass 'Main'
    javaRuntime '<NO RUNTIME>'
}
```

But no bundles are generated when `gradle jfxDeploy`. In fact, running `gradle jfxDeploy -i` show some interesting info:

```
Java runtime to be bundled: none, bundle will rely on locally installed runtimes
...
Skipping Mac Application Image because of configuration error The file for the Runtime/JRE directory does not exist.
Advice to Fix: Point the runtime parameter to a directory that containes the JRE.
Skipping DMG Installer because of configuration error The file for the Runtime/JRE directory does not exist.
Advice to Fix: Point the runtime parameter to a directory that containes the JRE.
Skipping PKG Installer because of configuration error The file for the Runtime/JRE directory does not exist.
Advice to Fix: Point the runtime parameter to a directory that containes the JRE.
Skipping Mac App Store Ready Bundler because of configuration error The file for the Runtime/JRE directory does not exist.
Advice to Fix: Point the runtime parameter to a directory that containes the JRE.
```

Ok, so maybe the plugin has some bugs. I try to generate the bundle with `javapackager`. I go to project folder and run the following:

```
javapackager -deploy -native image -srcfiles build/libs/ -outdir build/distributions -outfile Sample -appclass Main
```

The output is OK. The bundle is correctly generated with the JRE embedded. Now I try to generate a bundle without the JRE with this:

```
javapackager -deploy -native image -srcfiles build/libs/ -outdir build/distributions -outfile Sample -appclass Main -Bruntime=
```

(It's the same command appending `-Bruntime=` as explained in [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)).

The bundle is generated. Now its size is about 500 KB. But when I try to run it nothing happens. Running it in a terminal gives the following  (simplified) output:

```
$ Main.app/Contents/MacOS/Main
Failed to find library.:
Main:Failed to locate JNI_CreateJavaVM
Main:Failed to launch JVM
```

It seems that the bundle is not capable to start the local JVM. The jar is correctly generated and added to the bundle. Running it with `java -jar` runs the app but I don't know why it doesn't work when running the bundle

FYI, I'm running java 1.8.0_74, javac 1.8.0_74 and javapackager 8.0 in an OS X 10.11.2

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to current version of JDK?

Comment: I've just upgraded my JDK version. The issue is still present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javafx.plugin from shemnon isn't developed nor maintained anymore, for that reason I've created the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

The problem comes with the internal changes of the `.cfg`-file-format, they use INI-files now, but that is flawed in term of RUNTIME-configuration.

Official JDK-bug-tickets reported by me:
(jdk 9) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143314

(jdk 8) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143934

It should be enough to set some bundler-argument `launcher-cfg-format` to `cfg` within your build (or use the javafx-gradle-plugin, which includes that workaround automatically).

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin and the creator and maintainer of the javafx-gradle-plugin.

**UPDATE** *this got fixed and made available with JDK 8u92*

Comment: The related issue-ticket from the javafx-maven-plugin was this: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/167

Comment: Thanks, man. It worked. Until a full documentation is released I asume all the config parameters are those present at [JavaFXGradlePluginExtension.java](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/de/dynamicfiles/projects/gradle/plugins/javafx/JavaFXGradlePluginExtension.java)

Comment: @Dr.Pelocho yes, you are right! As this is my spare-time-project, I'm heavily behind my schedule ;) but documentation will be provided as soon as I can.